# como recorrer el json y mostrarlo en el component? Angular

Tags: angular, json, jsonarray

mi idea principal es poder hacer una lista con los li y que contengan un links a unas imágenes que obtengo de una base de datos y con css pasen solas. hasta hora lo único que conseguí es que pase [object  object] en la vista.

```html
<div id="contenedor-principal">
  <h3>PROYECTOS</h3>
  <div> 
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary" routerLink="/nuevahard" >Nueva Hard o Skill </button>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    
    <div class="div-titulo" *ngFor="let proyectos of proyecto" >
     <!-- <h2>{{Proyecto.nombrePro}}</h2>
      <h4>{{Proyecto.fecha}}</h4>-->
      <p>{{proyectos | json}}</p>
      <div class="card">
  
        <a href="{{proyectos.link}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" >
        
    
        <div class="slider">
          <ul>
              <li *ngFor="let proye of proyecto.proyectoimg">
               
                  <p>{{proye.link}}</p>
              
                <img src=>
              </li>
              <p></p>
          </ul>
      </div>
    
    </a>
   
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>{{proyectos.descripcioPro}}</p>
  </div>
  
  
  </div>
 

</div>
```

ts del componente donde cargo proyecto

```
export class ProyectosComponent implements OnInit {

  proyecto:Proyecto[]=[];
  
  constructor(private sProyecto:SProyectoService,private tokenService:TokenService) { }
  isLogged=false;
 
 
 ngOnInit(): void {

  

 this.cargarProyecto(); 

    
   
    if(this.tokenService.getToken())
    {
      this.isLogged=true;
    }else{
      this.isLogged=false;
    }


  }
  cargarProyecto():void{
    this.sProyecto.lista().subscribe(data=>{this.proyecto=data;});
    
  }
```

modelo de proyecto

```
export class Proyecto{


    id?:number;
    nombrePro: string;
    descripcioPro:string;
    link:string;
    ProyectoImg: object;
    fecha:string;
    
  
    constructor(nombrePro: string,descripcioPro:string,ProyectoImg:object,link:string,fecha:string)
      {
          this.nombrePro=nombrePro;
          this.descripcioPro=descripcioPro;
          this.link=link;
          this.ProyectoImg=ProyectoImg;
          this.fecha=fecha;
          
  
      }
  
  
   }
```

el service que uso:

```
export class SProyectoService {
  proyectoURL="http://localhost:8080/proyecto/"
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  public lista():Observable<Proyecto[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Proyecto[]>(this.proyectoURL+'lista');

  }
```

lo que recibo:

```
 { 
          "idProyecto": 1,
          "nombrePro": "Prueba,",
          "descripcioPro": "descripcion",
          "link": "link1", 
          "proyectoimg": [ 
             { "idProyectoimg": 1, "path": "path1", "link": "linkpath" },
             { "idProyectoimg": 2, "path": "path2", "link": "linkpath2" } 
          ], 
          "fecha": "30/12/01" 
        }
```

Obtengo el json anterior, logro que me muestre `nombrePro`, `descripcioPro` , `link` , `fecha`. Pero intento recorre la lista de json que esta dentro pero no encuentro la forma la cual seria `proyectoimg`.
Busco un ejemplo de como recórrelo  para mostrarlo en el component. todo esto en angular.
puse todo lo que se relaciona, pero mas allá lo que intento yo en mostrar en el html componet, es proyectoimg mas bien poder acceder a lo que tiene adentro tanto el path como el link.

Comment: Hola puedes agregar como haces esto: "logro que me muestre nombrePro, descripcioPro , link , fecha" , recuerda que debes mostrar un [example]

Comment: Como dice David, agrega el código de lo que has intentado. Si no, no podemos ayudarte